# Tricky JavaScript global composite operation task - Draw in overlap of two larger circles while excluding the overlap of 2 smaller circles

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing, globalcompositeoperation

I'm having a hard time drawing this problem using only one canvas. Global composite operations sort of feel like building a plane while flying it.

There are 2 sets of 2 circles, each set has the same center but a different radius. The overlapping area for the larger circles should be filled in, excluding the area of the smaller circles. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

[My desired output would be something along these lines.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/py62E.png)

I often start getting some desired features and then my lack of skill using globalcompositeoperation catches up to me.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(150, 150, 100, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "xor";

ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(250, 150, 100, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";

ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(150, 150, 120, 0, 2 * Math.PI); // Adjusted position
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```